# Add texts on top of videos

Tags: android, text

How do I add a text on top of a video. I only need to add text even if it is from start to end of the video.
Can you guys help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: What does on top mean? Y direction, or Z?

Comment: I'm talking about an actual text ON the video. I want to combine the text and the video. Sorry for not being specific.

Comment: On a separate layer above the video (z-order), or embedded in the actual video image content? It's best if you add more description to your questions so we understand the purpose/context.

Comment: I want the text embedded on the actual video.
Please forgive my lack of specification. I'm a filipino and only has a few grasp on English.

Answer (score 0):

Use a FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <VideoView />
    <LinearLayout />
</FrameLayout>
```

This would add the text on top of the video. Just like the subtitles are.